# Query Process ID (PID) from Windows Event Log

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to write a query that will extract the Process ID *(PID)* from a Windows Event log.

I'm dealing with Windows event ID: 1309

I have written several scripts that get me close but none that get me home. This one has come the closest:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0' -EntryType Warning -Newest 1 |
    where eventid -eq 1309 |
    Select message |
    Format-List |
    Out-File c:\temp\elogdata.txt
Select-String c:\temp\elogdata.txt -Pattern "process id:" -SimpleMatch
```

This is the output that I get:

```
C:\temp\elogdata.txt:20:              Process ID: 7332
```

I need to pipe that "7332" , from the "Process ID:" into another command such as TaskKill or ProcDump.

Strangely enough, when I try and run the `Select-String` on the output in memory I get nothing:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0' -EntryType Warning -Newest 1 |
    where eventid -eq 1309 |
    Select message |
    Format-List |
    Select-String -InputObject {$_} -Pattern "process id:"
```

I have also tried several `Get-WinEvent` scripts...

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName='application';ID='1309'} -MaxEvents 1 |
    Format-List |
    select message
```

Comment: Don't believe that this is possible since PID is based on active processes, while events are based on specific instances. You won't always have the same PID for a specific application based on when it was ran.

Comment: Also don't further process the output of a `Format-*` cmdlet (aside from Out-String/File) You'll get unexpected results. See `gci|fl|gm`

Comment: Hey Riley, I am going to tie this script to the 1309 event, so as soon as the event occurs this script will run and extract the PID, feed it into ProcDump, then kill this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* use `Format-*` cmdlets when further processing of your data is intended. What you want to do is *expand* the `Message` property and adjust your pattern, so that you extract the actual PID instead of the entire line. You also don't want to use a simple match here.

```
... |
    Select-Object -Expand Message |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<=process id:\s+)\d+' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value
```

`($<=...)` is a so-called positive lookbehind assertion that allows you to match something in your string without including that in the match that is returned. Essentially the pattern means "match `\d+` only if it's preceded by that other string".

Comment: Since I have run into situations where the bits and pieces of a script on a blog aren't enough for me to figure it out sometimes, here is the complete code that is working for me:    `$GetPID = Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0' -EntryType Warning -Newest 1 |
    where eventid -eq 1309 |
    Select-Object -Expand Message |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<=process id:\s+)\d+' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -Expand Value'